# Не удается написать условие проверки коллизии мяча с ракеткой (пинг-понг)

Tags: javascript, canvas

Пишу игру "Пинг-Понг" по [видеоуроку](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ju09womACpQ&index=3&list=LLRO5OVppiknYj3lvbJlSsaw). Точнее говоря, идею реализации взял оттуда, а код пишу по-своему (не совсем нравится его подход, но не суть).

Итак, очередь дошла до реализации детекции коллизии мяча со стиком: здесь-то я и застопорился.

Суть следующая: `requestAnimationFrame()` при первой же возможности выполняет метод `update()` класса `Pong`. Одной частью этого метода является определение коллизии мячика с ракеткой (строка "*"):

```
  update(dt) {
    this.ball.calcNewPos(dt);
    this.sticks[1].calcNewPos(this.ball);

    this.ball.reverseOnCollisionWithCanvas(this._canvas);
    this.ball.reverseOnCollisionWithSticks(this.sticks); // *

    this.draw();
  }
```

Суть этого метода в том, чтобы развернуть мяч, если он ударился о ракетку. А если пролетел выше или ниже - не трогать. Направление полета мяча задается его скоростью: отрицательной (полет влево) или положительной (полет вправо). Теперь метод `reverseOnCollisionWithSticks(this.sticks)`:

```
reverseOnCollisionWithSticks(sticks) {
    if (this.left < sticks[0].right) {
      this.reverse(1); // 1 means X
    }
  }
```

Это метод класса `Ball`, поэтому обращение к границам мяча тут происходит через `this`.

Что тут происходит сейчас. В метод попадают обе ракетки (но я пока проверяю только одну из них - левую, потому что ей управляет пользователь). Левая ракетка - `sticks[0]`. Я проверяю, что если левая граница мяча находится левее правой границы левой ракетки, значит произошло столкновение и мяч необходимо развернуть. Но это работает не так как надо. Мяч разворачивается даже если ракетка была ниже или выше него. Поэтому я добавил еще 2 проверки:

```
reverseOnCollisionWithSticks(sticks) {
    if (this.left < sticks[0].right && this.top < sticks[0].bottom && this.bottom > sticks[0].top) {
      this.reverse(1); // 1 means X
    }
  }
```

Теперь, чтобы мяч развернулся, нужно, чтобы одновременно:

1. Левая граница мяча стала левее правой границы ракетки
2. Верхняя граница мяча была выше нижней границы ракетки
3. Нижняя граница мяча была ниже верхней границы ракетки

Это работает, **но** (как же без него). Если мяч пролетел *над* ракеткой или *под* ракеткой, а потом ракетку резко дернули вверх или вниз соответственно, так, что верхняя (нижняя) граница мяча стала выше (ниже) нижней (верхней) границы ракетки, то детектится коллизия, только она происходит как будто бы за ракеткой, и мяч разворачивается. Такое поведение мне не подходит.

Как сделано на видео я не понимаю. На 19 минуте 56 секунде видео уже происходит какая-то несуразица. Он проверяет, что левая граница ракетки находится левее правой границы мяча и **одновременно с этим** правая граница ракетки находится правее левой границы мяча. Как такое может быть - непонятно чисто логически.

Прикладываю пример того, что уже есть, может так станет понятнее.

```js
class Dimension {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}

class Rect {
  constructor(x, y, w, h) {
    this.pos = new Dimension(x, y);
    this.size = new Dimension(w, h);
  }

  draw(context) {
    context.fillStyle = "#fff";
    context.fillRect(this.left, this.top, this.size.x, this.size.y);
  }

  get left() {
    return this.pos.x - this.size.x / 2;
  }

  get right() {
    return this.pos.x + this.size.x / 2;
  }

  get top() {
    return this.pos.y - this.size.y / 2;
  }

  get bottom() {
    return this.pos.y + this.size.y / 2;
  }
}

class Ball extends Rect {
  constructor(x, y, w, h) {
    super(x, y, w, h);
    this.vel = new Dimension(-150, -200);
  }

  calcNewPos(dt) {
    this.pos.x += this.vel.x * dt;
    this.pos.y += this.vel.y * dt;
  }

  reverseOnCollisionWithCanvas(canvas) {
    if (this.bottom > canvas.height || this.top < 0) {
      this.reverse(0); // 0 means Y
    }
  }

  reverseOnCollisionWithSticks(sticks) {
    if (this.left < sticks[0].right && this.top < sticks[0].bottom && this.bottom > sticks[0].top) {
      this.reverse(1); // 1 means X
    }
  }

  reverse(asix) {
    asix ? this.vel.x *= -1 : this.vel.y *= -1;
  }
}

class Stick extends Rect {
  constructor() {
    super(0, 0, 20, 140);
  }

  calcNewPos(ball) {
    this.pos.y = ball.pos.y;
  }
}

class Pong {
  constructor(params) {
    this._canvas = params.canvas;
    this._context = this._canvas.getContext(params.contextType);

    this.ball = new Ball(this._canvas.width / 2, this._canvas.height / 2, 10, 10);

    this.sticks = [
      new Stick,
      new Stick,
    ];

    this.sticks[0].pos.x = 40;
    this.sticks[1].pos.x = this._canvas.width - 40;
    this.sticks.forEach((stick) => {
      stick.pos.y = this._canvas.height / 2;
    });
  }

  track() {
    let lastUpdated;

    let callback = (ms) => {
      if (lastUpdated) {
        this.update((ms - lastUpdated) / 1000);
      }

      lastUpdated = ms;
      requestAnimationFrame(callback);
    };

    callback();
  }

  draw() {
    this._context.fillStyle = "#000";
    this._context.fillRect(0, 0, this._canvas.width, this._canvas.height);

    this.ball.draw(this._context);
    this.sticks.forEach((stick) => {
      stick.draw(this._context);
    });
  }

  update(dt) {
    this.ball.calcNewPos(dt);
    this.sticks[1].calcNewPos(this.ball);

    this.ball.reverseOnCollisionWithCanvas(this._canvas);
    this.ball.reverseOnCollisionWithSticks(this.sticks);

    this.draw();
  }
}

let pong = new Pong({
  canvas: document.querySelector("#ping-pong"),
  contextType: "2d",
});

pong.track();

pong._canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", (event) => {
  pong.sticks[0].pos.y = event.offsetY;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Ping-Pong</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="ping-pong" width="600px" height="400px"></canvas>
    <script src="pong0.js" defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Ах, да. Самое главное забыл. **Вопрос**: как правильно написать условие проверки?

Comment: слишком много лишнего текста. Никто не будет смотреть всё видео и сопоставлять что там у кого.....и главное.. так и не понятно в чем именно заключается проблема и что за  условие проверки вам нужно

Comment: @АлексейШиманский лишний текст можете не читать, если он для вас лишний, никто не заставляет. Кода только те куски, которые отвечают за возникшую проблему. Сниппет для наглядности и возможности попробовать-на-лету. Видео смотреть не застявляю. Указал время, на котором автор показал свое решение, тоже может пригодиться. В чем заключается проблема - расписано в тексте (не могу отседить коллизию). А условие проверки нужно как раз для проверки этой самой коллизии.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Как еще более подробно разжевать - не знаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простейшее решение: храним предыдущее положение мяча и проверяем, чтобы не только лишь левая граница была левее правой границы ракетки, но и чтобы до этого она была правее (таким образом, значит, мяч пересёк ракетку только что, а не когда-то давным давно).

```js
class Dimension {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}

class Rect {
  constructor(x, y, w, h) {
    this.pos = new Dimension(x, y);
    this.size = new Dimension(w, h);
  }

  draw(context) {
    context.fillStyle = "#fff";
    context.fillRect(this.left, this.top, this.size.x, this.size.y);
  }

  get left() {
    return this.pos.x - this.size.x / 2;
  }

  get right() {
    return this.pos.x + this.size.x / 2;
  }

  get top() {
    return this.pos.y - this.size.y / 2;
  }

  get bottom() {
    return this.pos.y + this.size.y / 2;
  }
}

class Ball extends Rect {
  constructor(x, y, w, h) {
    super(x, y, w, h);
    this.vel = new Dimension(-150, -200);
    this.prev = { x: 0.0, y: 0.0 };
  }

  get prevLeft() {
    return this.prev.x - this.size.x / 2;
  }

  calcNewPos(dt) {
    this.prev.x = this.pos.x;
    this.prev.y = this.pos.y;
    this.pos.x += this.vel.x * dt;
    this.pos.y += this.vel.y * dt;
  }

  reverseOnCollisionWithCanvas(canvas) {
    if (this.bottom > canvas.height || this.top < 0) {
      this.reverse(0); // 0 means Y
    }
  }

  reverseOnCollisionWithSticks(sticks) {
    if (this.prevLeft >= sticks[0].right && this.left < sticks[0].right && this.top < sticks[0].bottom && this.bottom > sticks[0].top) {
      this.reverse(1); // 1 means X
    }
  }

  reverse(asix) {
    asix ? this.vel.x *= -1 : this.vel.y *= -1;
  }
}

class Stick extends Rect {
  constructor() {
    super(0, 0, 20, 140);
  }

  calcNewPos(ball) {
    this.pos.y = ball.pos.y;
  }
}

class Pong {
  constructor(params) {
    this._canvas = params.canvas;
    this._context = this._canvas.getContext(params.contextType);

    this.ball = new Ball(this._canvas.width / 2, this._canvas.height / 2, 10, 10);

    this.sticks = [
      new Stick,
      new Stick,
    ];

    this.sticks[0].pos.x = 40;
    this.sticks[1].pos.x = this._canvas.width - 40;
    this.sticks.forEach((stick) => {
      stick.pos.y = this._canvas.height / 2;
    });
  }

  track() {
    let lastUpdated;

    let callback = (ms) => {
      if (lastUpdated) {
        this.update((ms - lastUpdated) / 1000);
      }

      lastUpdated = ms;
      requestAnimationFrame(callback);
    };

    callback();
  }

  draw() {
    this._context.fillStyle = "#000";
    this._context.fillRect(0, 0, this._canvas.width, this._canvas.height);

    this.ball.draw(this._context);
    this.sticks.forEach((stick) => {
      stick.draw(this._context);
    });
  }

  update(dt) {
    this.ball.calcNewPos(dt);
    this.sticks[1].calcNewPos(this.ball);

    this.ball.reverseOnCollisionWithCanvas(this._canvas);
    this.ball.reverseOnCollisionWithSticks(this.sticks);

    this.draw();
  }
}

let pong = new Pong({
  canvas: document.querySelector("#ping-pong"),
  contextType: "2d",
});

pong.track();

pong._canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", (event) => {
  pong.sticks[0].pos.y = event.offsetY;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Ping-Pong</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="ping-pong" width="600px" height="400px"></canvas>
    <script src="pong0.js" defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Все как обычно было слишком просто для того, чтобы додуматься до этого самому. Спасибо за помощь :)